# Am I writing my template tag urls correctly?

Tags: python, html, django

using Django 2 I am trying to add a shopping cart app to my django project. I am getting this error message: Reverse for 'add_cart' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['cart/add/(?P[0-9]+)/$']

From my understanding and doing some research I think my problem is that I am not inputting the correct urls in the template tags to link to my views. But I am only 4 weeks in to Django and am a bit lost.

I have tried changing the "{% url 'cart_remove' cart_item.product.id %}" and "{% url 'cart_add' cart_item.product.id %}" tags.

I have tried adjusting the app and project level urls.py.

I have tried to change the base.html, cart.html

I have tried changing the views and have read through every file a number of times trying to spot an error or typo.

I have been changing things around for about 5 hours now but nothing seems to work. as I said I think it is a problem with my template tags. I reckon I am confused and am trying to link the wrong thing.

cart.html

```py
{% for cart_item in cart_items %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{cart_item.product.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{cart_item.product.brand}}</td>
                    <td>{{cart_item.product.description}}</td>
                    <td>€{{cart_item.product.price}}</td>
                    <td>{{cart_item.sub_total}}</td>
                    <td>{{cart_item.quantity}}</td>
                    <td><a href="{% url 'cart_remove' cart_item.product.id%}">  
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign"></span></a></td>
                    <td><a href="{% url 'add_cart' cart_item.product.id %}">  
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span></a></td>
                </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

add_cart function in cart/views.py

```py
def add_cart(request, product_id):
    product = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
    try:
        cart = Cart.objects.get(cart_id=_cart_id(request))
    except Cart.DoesNotExist:
        cart = Cart.objects.create(
            cart_id = _cart_id(request)
        )
        cart.save()
    try:
        cart_item = CartItem.objects.get(product=product, cart=cart)
        if cart_item.quantity < cart_item.product.stock:
            cart_item.quantity += 1
            cart_item.save()
        else:
            messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO,
             'Sorry, no more of this item available')
    except CartItem.DoesNotExist:
        cart_item = CartItem.objects.create(
            product = product,
            quantity = 1,
            cart = cart
        )
        cart_item.save()
    return redirect('cart_detail')
```

cart/urls.py

```py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('add/<int:product_id>/', views.add_cart, name='add_cart'),
    path('', views.cart_detail, name='cart_detail'),
    path('remove/<int:product_id>/', views.cart_remove, name='cart_remove'),
    path('full_remove/', views.full_remove, name='full_remove'),
]
```

Template paths

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
         os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'shop', 'templates/'),
         os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'cart', 'templates/'),],
```

Project level urls.py

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('landing.urls')),
    path('shop/', include('shop.urls')),
    path('cart/', include('cart.urls')),   
]
```

My expected result is for the landing page to show when i connect to my local server and for the shop.html page to load when I click on the shop link in my nav bar. At the moment I am getting the error: Reverse for 'add_cart' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['cart/add/(?P[0-9]+)/$']

Comment: Your code all looks fine, the error message suggests that the `cart_item` in your loop doesn't have a product.id (with which to create the URL), are you sure that all your cart_items do have products?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes I believe so, I am kind of unsure as to what the error even is. This is my first time using a framework. I think this is the problem "cart_item.product.id" I am not sure where I am getting this and think that it's possible that this is wrong and I maybe need to change it to cart_items or products.id. Is there any chance you could tell me where I could check that out?

Comment: So the error is that you have defined a 'route' or a 'path' which is /cart/add/ and then a number (the product id).  However when Django tries to render the template, there is no product ID, and so it is stuck as to what URL to create.
So what I think you ought to do is try:
```{% for cart_item in cart_items %}
{{cart_item.product}}
{% endfor %}```
To make sure that your cart_item actually has a product attached

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply again. It turns out that I was sending "product" from the views to the template rather than "products" Thank you for your replies, they were instrumental in finding the error. I really appreciate you taking the time to help me.

Comment: No problem! Best of luck